# Ubuntu running very slowly on VirtualBox VM

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualization

As stated, my VM is running very slowly.

Guest: Ubuntu 14.04 'Trusty Tahr'

host specs:

- Laptop
- Windows 10
- Intel i5-6200U 2.4Ghz processor
- 8gb ram

It is unbearable, I can't write in the console as it takes half a minute for text to update on the command line, or not at all

Things I have tried:

- Disabling/enabling 3D acceleration
- Setting RAM to 2 gigs
- Setting VRAM to 128MB
- Enabling 2 cores
- Processor cap is at 100%
- Laptop power set to best performance

More info:

- VirtualBox version 5.2.20
- I have the same problem on another VM:18.0.4LTS.
- Updating the guest is not an option, as it is a pre configured OS for a project. (This is not the problem probably as the same problem appears on LTS)
- It is possible that LTS started slowing down after installing guest additions.
- CPU and RAM on host (task manager) are about 50-70% tops when running vm with other programs running in addition on the host.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

thanks

Comment: How many CPUs are the VMs using? Are virtualization options (VT-x, Hyper-V and such) enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Well, my Ubuntu VMs have fewer resources than yours, and mine are fast and instantly responsive. I'd check that Windows isn't throttling your VM resources.

Comment: Check disk loading.  Both host and guest doesn't have sufficient RAM for disk buffer.  If your using traditional HDD it could be a huge pain.

Comment: @xenoid I checked using the method shown [here](https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-find-out-if-intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-virtualization-technology-is-supported-in-windows-10-windows-8-windows-vista-or-windows-7-machine/) using the task manager, and virtualization is enabled. I fiddled with the VM options again and disabling "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" solved it. Guest runs pretty smoothly now. Does it do any harm if that option is disabled?

Comment: No, it just makes things **very slow**.

Comment: You should also consider using KVM/virt-manager instead of VirtualBox as most people see even more performance improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

1. Shut down the VM
2. Turn off Enable VT-x/AMD-V under System > Acceleration in the vm settings
3. Boot VM, should run much better now but still a bit slow
4. Shut down VM
5. Enable the option again
6. Boot VM, should run smoothly now

Comment: works for r5-4600u laptop, thanks!